# Quick SQL query to find if found in mySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name `wishlist`. In this I have two fields `user_id` and `product_id`.
In a page, I will check if the `$user_id` and `$product_id` variables are found in this table.
If are they found in the same row then a *found message* is appeared, otherwise a *not found message*. It may only be found once.

How can I do this?

This is my `wishlist` table

```
user_id product_id
1       13
2       23
```

and suppose the `$user_id =  1` and `product_id = 13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select exists (
    select 1
    from wishlist
    where user_id    = $user_id
      and product_id = $product_id
)
```

Some databases even have special optimizations for the `select exists (select 1 ...)` construct so they can short circuit it rather than finding all the possible matches.

Comment: Thank you. What about the if? Should I use a `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { }` ?

Comment: @mtopia: That query will return a boolean result, so grab the single column in the single row that it returns, if it is 1 then something was found and if it is 0 then nothing was found.

Comment: I did this `if ($already) {
  echo "found";
} else {
  echo "not found";
}` but always echo me the found message

Comment: @mtopia: [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a result set for SELECTs, you need to hand that to `mysql_fetch_array` (or one of the other fetch functions) to get at the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here if PHP that does what you want. You may use what `mysql_fetch_array()` returns to print the contents. More information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE user_id = ´$user_id´ OR product_id = ´$product_id´");

if (mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  echo "found";
} else {
  echo "not found"
}
```